# Hibernate Annotations Id for table with no primary key

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a table that has no primary key, and one cannot be created either. I can construct a unique key using three columns of this table. Now hibernate demands an id for every annotated class, how do i satisfy this id with the unique Id I can create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an [entity type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html) then you should use a composite key. This can be done by moving primary key fields to separate class and mapping that in entity class with an @Id annotation.

See [Mapping composite primary keys and foreign keys to composite primary keys](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177)

If it is not an entity but a value type you should map it accordingly.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1696146/324900 and [Entity and value types in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8038552/324900)

Comment: yes you can. But you said you don't have a primary key then this table is not an 'entity' theoritically. This should be part of another entity, you can map multiple tables to single entity in Hibernate.

Comment: Hibernate (nor JPA in general) does not care if you physically have a primary key defined on the table.  You just need a column or group of columns that uniquely identify each row.  The columns must all be non-nullable.

Comment: @Steve, seems I misunderstood the question updated my answer to put composite id as first option.